# DocumentSnapshot (Firestore) to Kotlin Object that contains a list of custom Object

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object `User`:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
object User {
val firstName: String = ""
val lastName: String = ""
val employeeId: String = ""
val city: String = ""
val email: String = ""
var salaries = mutableListOf<Salary>()
}
```

and Salary looks like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
object Salary {
var employeeId: String? = ""
var value: Int? = 0
var startDate:Date = Date()
}
```

When retriving user data from Firestore I'm using this code to parse `DocumentSnapshot` from Firestore:

```
documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
```

everything works like it should besides 'list of salaries'. The size of the list is correct (in my case is 3) but it is the same element three times instead of 3 different elements - any idea on how can I fix that...? :S

exact code:

```
 fun getUser(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return Observable.create<Boolean> {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid).addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {
            override fun onEvent(p0: DocumentSnapshot?, p1: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                if (p0!!.exists()) {
                     p0.toObject(User::class.java)
                    it.onNext(true)
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
        )
    }
}
```

db structure:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: Can you please add the entire code that you are using to get the data? Please also add your database structure where you are hosting those 3 elements.

Comment: @AlexMamo sure - just a sec

Comment: Ya, to see it more clearly.

Comment: @AlexMamo I add that to the question

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your database, the `salaries` property is not a list, is an `array` that contains in terms three other objects. When you are adding data to a Cloud Firestore database using `mutableListOf<Salary>()` it doesn't mean that the data will be stored as a list, it means that you'll store the data as an array, where the keys are numbers and the values are the actual `Salary` objects. Note, the `List` is no a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) in Cloud Firestore.

So to solve this, just get the desired user document and get those there salaries from the `salaries` property as a `List`. But note, even if `salaries` object is stored in the database as an array, the object that is returned is an `ArrayList`, not an `array`. Now just iterate over the list and get all those three objects which are of type `Salary`. That's it!

PS. Be also sure to have all those three salary objects in your database, as different objects. As I see in your picture, the first two are the same.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- salaries (collection)
         |
         --- userId (document)
               |
               --- userSalaries (collection)
                       |
                       --- salaryId (document)
                             |
                             --- //salary properties
```

Comment: @AlexMemo ty very much, will try it at once - but don't understand the part when U say "is an object (more precisely a map) " because when I hover over "salaries"- node in console it show ups that it is an "array" :S  -am I missunderstanding sometthing here..?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that between the number and the `Salary` object there are no colons (`:`), so you are correct is an array. Please see my updated andwer.

Comment: U are awsome- ty for explanation and your time -saved me a headache:), have a good day sir!

Comment: damn it , can not make it work - what I did is: var salaries = p0.get("salaries") as List<Salary>  but  that gives error: 'HashMap cannot be cast to Salary' which means that it retrives a list of Hashmaps instead of Salaries so for me to cast that to make it a Salary object I have to iterrate trough the Map /create new Salary Object for iterration /and assign all values "manualy"- feels like a hustle so pls tell me that I do that incorrwct:S

Comment: You need to get a list of `Salary` objects. Try to iterate over that map. What does it contain, `Salary` objects?

Comment: well that is exacly how it looks like: " var salaries = p0.get("salaries") as  List<HashMap<String,Any>>" where "key" is a name of Salary property (like "startDate","monthSalary" etc and values are ofc values of thoes properties) I can not make p0.get("salaries")  to retrive Salary Objects in any form :/

Comment: In this case, those are only the properties and not the Salary objects it self. But if I were you, I'll change the database structure a little bit by creating a top level collection named `salaries`, and inside I'll add as documents salary objects. The key of the salary object should be the user id. `db.collection("salaries").document(userId).get()...` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176894/discussion-between-pb4now-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Please see again my updated answer with the database schema that will help you achieve this. Is a better idea in my opinion than the last one.

Comment: yes, that  works as well (y) - but by changing Salary from "object" to "class" I don't need to change anything in my database because it parse everyting correcly when I use p0.toObject(User::class.java):)

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is that Salary was declared as an `object` and not a `class` (that's why I had the same element multiple times in my **salaries** list)
so `object -> class`